# Angular get SUM of Array with condition of other key

Tags: arrays, angular

How can I get sum of array if sel1 or sel2 or sel3 == 1 out of following Array?

```
[ 
  { "sel1": 0, "sel2": 1, "sel3": 0, "price": 10 }, 
  { "sel1": 0, "sel2": 1, "sel3": 0, "price": 15 }, 
  { "sel1": 1, "sel2": 0, "sel3": 1, "price": 20 }, 
]
```

If I would like to sum all "price" my function looks like this and works fine:

```
   this.sum = this.array.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
      return prev + cur.price;
    }, 0);
```

Is it possible to change function to get only sum of sel2?

Comment: Your given data does not make sense, please double-check it.

Comment: Why should my question makes no sense? I have array with products selected and only wants sum of a few of them. Thats all about it.

Comment: Not your question, but your example data. This is just not a valid construct.

Comment: @SaschaK You array must be in the form of `[ { 0: {` with comma at the end of each objects.

Comment: Okay sorry changed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use key to check, whether that item has selected product. Then only sum with current price. else return past accumulated price.

```js
const list = [
  { sel1: 0, sel2: 1, sel3: 0, price: 10 },
  { sel1: 0, sel2: 1, sel3: 0, price: 15 },
  { sel1: 1, sel2: 0, sel3: 1, price: 20 },
];
// item[key] === 1 to chek product is selected.
const price = (key, data = []) =>
  data.reduce((sum, item) => (item[key] === 1 ? sum + item.price : sum), 0);
console.log(price("sel3", list));
console.log(price("sel2", list));
console.log(price("sel1", list));
```

Comment: Hi seems this is what I was searching for. If I put code into my function it`s not returning me sum it returns price1price2price3. Maybe you can put your code into my example above? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` your data array to a an array of only sel2 elements and then `reduce` them.

Example of such map would be

```js
this.array.map(entry => entry.sel2) // This returns an array of 'sel2'
```